# err message : Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first

Tags: android, firebase

I can't initialize Firebase app first

I added these plug-in on gradle:app

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
```

(I tried to make them same version)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Also I added it to gradle:project

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

Last, I Added it to onCreate() in MainActivity

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

<<<< AndroidManifest >>>>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.firebasetest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

<<<< MainActivity >>>>

```
package com.example.firebasetest;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    String email;
    String password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        ...

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.

        ...
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser currentUser) {
    }
}
```

<<<<<<<<<< gradle:app >>>>>>>>>>

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.firebasetest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

<<<<<<<<<< gradle:project >>>>>>>>>>

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I expected it worked correctly.
But after the app installed, it even doesn't show the MainActivity

the error Message are these :

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.firebasetest, PID: 18544
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firebasetest/com.example.firebasetest.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.firebasetest. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3229)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.firebasetest. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(SourceFile:218)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source:1)
        at com.example.firebasetest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7317)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3066)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3229) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)

Comment: `Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this line

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

With this line

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

I think there is a bug with google play services version 4.1.0

Comment: Yes it's a big problem with this version

Comment: Found the issue https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1445

Answer (score 1):

make sure to put `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in app gradle